# VS2010 WPF Designer and assembly references

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, reference

I have a situation while developing a WPF MVVM application. After some extensive searching I'll try to explain the experienced behaviour on SO, and hope someone has a solution.

The WPF application under development, has a reference to a local developed "Infrastructure" assembly. This assembly mainly consists of classes to commmunicate with our WCF services.

This assembly has a assembly reference to a second assembly, "Ninject.Extensions.WCF", whoose content is used in some functionalities.

When I include a reference to the "Infrastructure" assembly, i get a VS2010 designer error that it cannot find the "Ninject.Extensions.WCF" assembly within a couple of seconds after triggering a local build.

This all makes sense because the designer "probably" traverses all referenced assemblies for definitions.

In this particular case, the assembly it's trying to load has nothing to do with WPF, so I can live with the designer not trying to resolve the assembly.

Is there a way to "tell" the designer to ignore these missing referenced assemblies instead of throwing an exception?

Comment: Not unless you programatically load your infrastructure assembly, ie don't have it in your design environment. Why not just add a reference to this Ninject assembly, without it VS can't compile, and if you explicitly load, it will need it to do any debugging.

Comment: The ninject assembly is only used for WCF services which also use the same infrastructure assembly. Maybe my best shot is to move the Ninject dependant code into "yet another" assembly. I'd rather not do that though, trying to keep the assembly reference count to a minumum ;)

Comment: Seems a lot of bother over nothing to me. Rationalising it for deployment certainly. Making sure your dependencies are current certainly. We tend to build this sort of thing design or full build time by getting the dependant builds to thow it at a common bin directory, and then just add a file reference. Aside from issues manageing them oin occasion having more dlls to depend on is way better than ending up monolithic....